# Android: Unicode/Charset problems when sending an SMS (sendTextMessage)

Tags: android, sms, special-characters, character-encoding

Basically I have a working application that sends an SMS after receiving an SMS.

**Everything works fine**, except when the SMS text **to send** has "special chars", ie "é,à,í,ç", etc.

I've tried many things including charset conversion but I simply can't make it work... the msgText always comes back with charset encoding problems.

Here's the part where the message is sent:

```
if (msgText.length() > 160) {
    ArrayList msgTexts = sm.divideMessage(msgText);
    sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(PhoneNumber, null, msgTexts, null, null);
} else {
    try {
        sm.sendTextMessage(PhoneNumber, null, msgText, null, null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's the charset conversion function I tried (but didn't help), that I applied on msgText:

```
public static String formatCharset(String txtInicial) {
    //-- Please notice this is just for reference, I tried every charset from/to conversion possibility. Even stupid ones and nothing helped.

    /*try {//-- Seems simpler, it should do the same as below, but didn't help
        msgText = new String(msgText.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    Charset charsetOrigem = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    CharsetEncoder encoderOrigem = charsetOrigem.newEncoder();
    Charset charsetDestino = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    CharsetDecoder decoderDestino = charsetDestino.newDecoder();

    String txtFinal = "";

    try {
        ByteBuffer bbuf = encoderOrigem.encode(CharBuffer.wrap( txtInicial ));
        CharBuffer cbuf = decoderDestino.decode(bbuf);
        txtFinal = cbuf.toString();
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (txtFinal.length() == 0) txtFinal = txtInicial;

    return txtFinal;
}
```

Near desperation I even tried the solution for unicode messaging in here (didn't help as well):

http://since2006.com/blog/android-send-unicode-message/

Anyway, here's the (cleaned up - package is com.THE.APPLICATION, main activity is MAINACT) LogCat for when it crashes (when trying to send the message, after receiving one):

```
WARN/dalvikvm(28218): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7f0)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED (has extras) } in com.THE.APPLICATION.SMSReceiver@44acd880
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:905)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1253)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:369)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:87)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at com.THE.APPLICATION.MAINACT.sendMessage(MAINACT.java:214)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at com.THE.APPLICATION.SMSReceiver.onReceive(SMSReceiver.java:24)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:892)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28218):     ... 9 more
```

Sample of message text to send with issues:

```
VERBOSE/debug_tag(28218): msgText is: possÃ­vel.
```

So, it *reads* **possÃ­vel** when it should *be* **possível**

Please some enlightened soul help me out. He/She'll have a special place in my heart! :)

Edit: If the special place in my heart doesn't cut it, I'm willing to pay a few bucks for a working solution...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, this seems to have been solved by simply using `sendMultipartTextMessage` instead of `sendTextMessage` for the messages.

Who would've thought... it kind of makes sense because unicode characters use more "space" than "normal" ones.

Comment: When I send this way, '?' is displaying for each unicode characters. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

I have used this code to convert UTF-8 characters into ASCII. Then sending of SMS works and I can use 160 characters:

```
private static final String PLAIN_ASCII = "AaEeIiOoUu" // grave
        + "AaEeIiOoUuYy" // acute
        + "AaEeIiOoUuYy" // circumflex
        + "AaOoNn" // tilde
        + "AaEeIiOoUuYy" // umlaut
        + "Aa" // ring
        + "Cc" // cedilla
        + "OoUu" // double acute
;

private static final String UNICODE = "\u00C0\u00E0\u00C8\u00E8\u00CC\u00EC\u00D2\u00F2\u00D9\u00F9"
        + "\u00C1\u00E1\u00C9\u00E9\u00CD\u00ED\u00D3\u00F3\u00DA\u00FA\u00DD\u00FD"
        + "\u00C2\u00E2\u00CA\u00EA\u00CE\u00EE\u00D4\u00F4\u00DB\u00FB\u0176\u0177"
        + "\u00C3\u00E3\u00D5\u00F5\u00D1\u00F1"
        + "\u00C4\u00E4\u00CB\u00EB\u00CF\u00EF\u00D6\u00F6\u00DC\u00FC\u0178\u00FF"
        + "\u00C5\u00E5" + "\u00C7\u00E7" + "\u0150\u0151\u0170\u0171";

// remove accentued from a string and replace with ascii equivalent
public static String convertNonAscii(String s) {
    if (s == null)
        return null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int n = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int pos = UNICODE.indexOf(c);
        if (pos > -1) {
            sb.append(PLAIN_ASCII.charAt(pos));
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using this command line:

```
Html.fromHtml(new String(myString.getBytes("UTF-8"))).toString();
```

and my SMS message looks perfect.

Comment: Hi, Christian.
I haven't coded for Android natively in quite a few years, but it seems like that's a much cleaner solution that maybe didn't exist at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I has the same problem with special characters. When I change message MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH to 70 everything works well. Look at that link:

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/special-characters-in-sms-turn-them-shorter-70-characters-old-issue-never-solved.1030577/

This is my code:

```
    public static void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message, Context context) {

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    int MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 70;

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    PendingIntent sentPI;
    sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);

    try {
        if(message.length() > MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
            ArrayList<String> messageList = SmsManager.getDefault().divideMessage(message);
            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, messageList, null, null);
        } else {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsProvider", "" + e);
    }
}
```

Of course you can insert a controller that will check if the message contains some special character and then change MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH from 160 to 70. I always have special characters in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use 160 chars if it's 7-bit encoding. If you use 140 chars, it should work without sendMultipartTextMessage because you're using 8-bit chars (UTF-8).

Comment: Makes sense, right? But it doesn't work without sendMultipartTextMessage with 8-bit chars (obviously it works for 7-bit chars without it). I feel something's not really quite right in there.