# Can't send sms messages which contains umlauts chars (programmatically)

Tags: android, sms, chars

I'm sending SMS by using the following method:

```
sendTextMessage(address, null, text, null, null);
```

Everything works ok while using english chars, but if the text contains at least one umlaut char the sms isn't being sent.

Please note that I don't get any exception, it seems that everything works as it should be but the SMS isn't being sent.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `sendMultipartTextMessage()`,. per http://stackoverflow.com/a/4642476/115145 ?

Comment: How many characters do you have in the text message?

Comment: sendMultipartTextMessage() works!!! thanks, but i heard that some devices won't get the SMS properly while using this method.