# UTF 8 encoding in Android SMS app

Tags: java, android, sms, utf

I am working on writing  creating a new app which will send messages to any mobile device native SMS app.

while sending messages, instead of ASCII, I am using some UTF-8 encoding characters which are being replaced in between few ASCII characters of a string.

I am facing an exception while sending the message after giving the recipients number. The above utility method will look up for corresponding UTF code, when I send on button click, 
following exception comes:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
android.telephony.SmsMessage$SubmitPdu.<init>(SmsMessage.java:168)
android.telephony.SmsMessage.getSubmitPdu(SmsMessage.java:1114)
android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:248)
android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:122)
com.mastpro.dpsu.stegosms.SendCipherMsgActivity.onSendClick(SendCipherMsgActivity.java:60)
```

Comment: Please post your code for SendCipherMsgActivity.java, especially line 60. Your problem is impossible to understand from the description alone.

Answer (score 0):

You should use sendMultipartTextMessage instead of sendTextMessage for the message, see [Android: Unicode/Charset problems when sending an SMS (sendTextMessage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233461/android-unicode-charset-problems-when-sending-an-sms-sendtextmessage)