# How to send SMS in languages other than english using SmsManager?

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have tried to send `Text Message` using `SmsManager` in android. Message is delivering fine. When i tried to send message in different language it delivers as `??????`. I don't know what's the problem.

```
try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                String phno = "+919715361062";
                String msg = "டெஸ்டிங்";
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phno, null, msg, null, null);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: before sending message change massage in his language and send..

Comment: @Destro after typed the text in my language i converted it to `Basic Latin`. that helped me to send text in what language i want.

Comment: language is not convert in run time.

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```
ArrayList<String> arrSMS = smsManager.divideMessage("Text to send");
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage("Number", null, arrSMS, null, null);
```

Comment: converting string to `Basic Latin` helped me. e.g `String msg = "\u0b9f\u0bc6\u0bb8\u0bcd\u0b9f\u0bbf\u0b99\u0bcd";`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sendMultipartTextMessage().

Look at this question: [Android: Unicode/Charset problems when sending an SMS (sendTextMessage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233461/android-unicode-charset-problems-when-sending-an-sms-sendtextmessage)

Comment: converting string to Basic Latin helped me. e.g String msg = "\u0b9f\u0bc6\u0bb8\u0bcd\u0b9f\u0bbf\u0b99\u0bcd";