# Is it possible to change the fonts of unicode via android app

Tags: android

I want to change the font of my phone via my android app.If  i applied fonts on my  android app in edit text that font style must be show on phone messaging app edit text field. 
And also i make a custom keyboard app for that  .In phone messaging app it show my fonts style keyboard but not showing in edit text field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview

Answer (score 0):

Use Typeface to add edditional font to the textview. Download and save the font in the asset folder and use Typeface in the textView or editText

[How to change the font on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)

```
 Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf"); 
 txtyour.setTypeface(type);
```

Comment: Thanks but  my problem is that i want font style (which i save in my app) will be same outside my app like when i closed my app and open phone messaging app it  should show my font  style on that messaging on its edittext field.

Comment: Hope this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233461/android-unicode-charset-problems-when-sending-an-sms-sendtextmessage